# How to use SurfaceView in android applications?

Tags: android

What is a SurfaceView ?? Is anybody have example code which uses SurfaceView ?? If there please reply me.

Thanks,
Yugandhar

Answer (score 1):

As always, check the official documentation first.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html

SurfaceView is new, so you would have to wait a while for it to appear here:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html

Comment: It's not new *(exists since API 1, was always used for camera previews, ...)*, so don't have too high hopes that you'll ever get a "Hello SurfaceView" tutorial in the official docs. :)